# How can I intercept calls to lock.acquire() and lock.release() in the threading module automatically?

Tags: python, multithreading, mutex, instrumentation

My goal is to be able to recognize at runtime directly that a certain `lock.acquire()` and `lock.release()` calls were made and be able to get info on this `lock` object.
So, in theory I do not know where or if they are called - therefore, I don't want to use decorators or subclass the lock class.

My approach:
The problem is that when using [sys.settrace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace), the calls to `acquire()` and `release()` do not cause me to enter a new scope and thus I'm still in the same same scope without knowing these functions were even called.
This gets me to think that the C code is executed directly for a lock from `_thread` module (is that correct?)

So, is there a way within this approach to do that?

Comment: In theory, monkey-patching the functions directly in `threading` should work, although I don't see how settrace would help you here.

Comment: @Norrius Yeah that could work, but I'm trying to make such calls rather dynamically and not just for my own threading class.

Comment: If you do that before any other code is imported, that would work for all other usage of `threading.Lock` too. Basically, right at the startup, do `from threading import Lock; Lock.acquire = your_function`. It's a massive hack though.

Comment: @Norrius Okay fair enough; however, if the code uses a lock with context management like `with lock: ...` then how could we similarly extend this

Comment: Well, context managers are implemented through [`__enter__` and `__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__), so you could overwrite those.